# JS 2D array cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array items, that always has 7 columns. Using the code provided, I can display each element of the array with out error. However when I try to access the array at the end like this:

`<button onclick="delete_item(items[i][6])">Delete</button>`

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '6' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (account.php:64)
onclick @ account.php:64
```

Rest of my code is:

```
for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                document.write('<div style="border-style:solid;padding:15px;background-color:whitesmoke;"><img src="'+items[i][5]+'" style="width:8%"><br><b style="font-size:20px;">'+items[i][0]+'</b><br>$'+items[i][1]+'<div style="float:right"><a href="item.php?itemid='+items[i][6]+'&itemname='+items[i][0]+'" style="font-size:20px">Click Here for the Item Information</a></div><br>Seller: '+items[i][2]+'<br>Description: '+items[i][3]+'<br> <button onclick="delete_item(items[i][6])">Delete</button></div>');
document.write('<br>');
                }
```

Also, by using `<button onclick="delete_item(items[1][6])">Delete</button>` instead of using 'i', everything works fine. What would cause this, because shouldn't using i

Comment: my bad it is 7 columns. typo in the question

Comment: show us `items`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: show what's in the array `items` buddy..

Answer (score 0):

Use this below one because in your code snapshot, I not referring index. Its trey to read I kay from your array and that not available, try below code:

```
<button onclick="delete_item(items["+i+"][6])">Delete</button>
```

Comment: gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some quotes around your variable:

`'<button onclick="delete_item(\''+items[i][6]+ '\')">Delete</button>'`

```js
let a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"];
let b = ["x","b","c","d","e","f","y"];

let items = [a,b];

var delete_item = function(item){
 console.log("delete: " + item)
}

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  document.write('<div style="border-style:solid;padding:15px;background-color:whitesmoke;"><img style="width:8%"><br><b style="font-size:20px;">' + items[i][0] + '</b><br>$' + items[i][1] + '<div style="float:right"></div><br>Seller: ' + items[i][2] + '<br>Description: ' + items[i][3] + '<br> <button onclick="delete_item(\''+items[i][6]+ '\')">Delete</button></div>');
  document.write('<br>');
}
```

Also, you could consider using `document.createElement` and `addEventListener`.